# configure: error: LDFLAGS

Tags: software-installation, ld, trace, tracing

I am trying to install LTTng.

I was installing lttng-tools-2.6.0 and got the following error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find libuuid uuid_generate nor libc uuid_create. Use LDFLAGS=-Ldir to specify their location.
```

I don't know how to specify `-L/usr/local/lib` in `LDFLAGS`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `LDFLAGS` as an environment variable before `configure`:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib ./configure
```

or as a parameter to `configure`:

```
./configure LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: checking for uuid_generate in -luuid... no
checking for uuid_create in -lc... no
configure: error: Cannot find libuuid uuid_generate nor libc uuid_create. Use LDFLAGS=-Ldir to specify their location.                                             //I am still getting the error

Comment: Do you have libuuid installed anywhere?